# How to clip an enormous shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, algorithm

The images below is a snippet of 2 shapefiles.

1) every building in the UK (13,971,598 features)

2) blue polygons

The goal is to clip or select all the buildings that fall within the blue polygon features. I'm wondering what method would be most time efficient. I have tried select by location but ran into the error posted below. Other than using GDAL/OGR or SAGA algorithms to clip the buildings layer which I imagine would take >24hrs, would there be an alternative method? I would be interested to know how you would tackle this so that I may test it.
My experience of working outside of QGIS desktop is very limited so please go easy on any jargon that you might find someone like myself to be unfamiliar with.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried to select by location? also, QGIS' *clip* does use OGR under the hood, I guess the speed gain of bash vs. in-QGIS would be neglectable (but not sure). what I'm trying to say is; there are tools (I like to mention PostgreSQL/PostGIS), but since it's there already (and unless you want to do that on a daily basis), try the options QGIS has to offer first. getting you set-up and those large datasets into a DB for example could actually take a lot longer...,)

Comment: What QGIS version are you using? You can try the tools from the processing toolbox. The standard tools are being exchanged by the new ones in the newer QGIS versions. But they should already be available in the older version in the processing toolbox. The have the same name there, but work different.

Comment: I'm using version 2.18.14

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the place ask for "guides". Ask a question to a concrete problem. Did you even try to google "ogr clip shapefile"? There you can find some code you could try in a few minutes. And if it's not useful or too slow then ask something like: "I've tried 'this' and 'this', is posible to clip it faster?" and maybe we can help you with another alternatives.

Comment: how can a blue dot contain a building?

Comment: @IanTurton could you by any chance make the question live again? I've made some amendments.

Comment: if you have edited then it will be in the reopen queue for people to consider

Comment: Did you try QGIS' clip algorithm? Its very much faster than "select by location" in qgis 2.18. Or try 3.0, where Select by Location is MUCH improved.

Comment: Don't use screenshots for error messages, they are not searchable and are hard to read.